# Artin's theorem and signature

Tags: group-theory, permutations, galois-theory

I learnt here or on MO that a theorem of Artin states that the only elements of the absolute Galois group of the rationals of finite order are the identity and the complex conjugation.
Can we thus see the map
$$\mathcal{G}_{\mathbb{Q}} \mapsto \text{Tor}(\mathcal G_{\mathbb Q})$$

as an analogue of the signature morphism?

Comment: Is mathjax broken?

Comment: How would you define that map? $\text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ is extremely nonabelian.

Comment: I define $\mathrm{Tor}(G)$ as the group generated by the torsion elements of $G$.

Comment: The theorem as you state it is incorrect. What's instead true is that every element of finite order is either trivial or *conjugate to* complex conjugation, that is, there is an automorphism $\sigma$ such that it is given by $x\mapsto\sigma^{-1}(\overline{\sigma(x)})$. That way or another, I agree it is unclear how you wish to define the map in question.

Comment: Ok, so a better statement would be "there are only two conjugation classes of torsion elements of $\mathcal{G}_{\mathbb{Q}}$, namely the ones of the identity and of the complex conjugation", right?